# Disable/remove "more notifications" and always display all notifications in Notification Center

Tags: macos, notifications, monterey

so just the other day I finally set up new MBP M1 (made a jump from MPB early 2013 with Catalina) and was greeted with updated Notification Center. It's quite fine but one thing is annoying the hell out of me - "x more notifications" -- is there ANY way to always display all notifications?